# Show <li> from bottom to top

Tags: html, css

excuse my English if I have a mistake.
I want to show a list like this in HTML5:

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

It works perfectly, but I want to start showing the list from bottom to top, like "Watsap" messages.

Comment: Order them in reverse?

Comment: I assume these dynamic. If they are, @oGeez makes a valid suggestion...

Comment: I do not want to order in reverse, I want to show in order but scroll start from bottom to top.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try `position: absolute` with `bottom: 0`
http://jsfiddle.net/FBzg7/

Comment: I may have understood your question wrong ... My solution offers a way to visually show the last one at the bottom, but I guess what you want is to show the first one in the existing hierarchy at the bottom. As @oGeez said, you will need to order them reverse

Comment: How about prepending instead of appending? do you use jQuery?

Comment: Yes, I am using jQuery!

Comment: I use prepend, it is not what I want, but is another way to show data.

Thank you Mabedan ;)